# O que é e como funciona os Claims no asp.Net identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

O que é e como funciona os Claims no asp.Net identity?

Em que exemplo de uso real usariamos Claims?

Qual a vantagem de usa-los?

Códigos de exemplos?

Answer (score 2):

Autenticação usando claims ao invés de atribuir usuários a grupos, você seta claims ao usuário. Desta forma, você tem uma flexibilidade maior na hora de gerenciar permissões.

Links:

http://elemarjr.net/2013/08/16/claims-based-access-control-com-claims-no-net-4-5/

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/01/leveraging-claims-based-security-in-aspnet-45.aspx

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/09/01/going-beyond-usernames-and-roles.aspx